# Render Empty XML Elements as Parent Elements

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a strange requirement where an application consuming some XML that my application is generating actually needs empty elements to be serialized as parent elements. For example:

```
<element foo="bar" />
```

should be:

```
<element foo="bar"></element>
```

I'm not aware of any way that the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) allows you to change this. Does anybody know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Looks like somebody rolled his own XML "parsing" ;)

Comment: Yep...That's probably exactly what happened. It's frustrating.

Comment: What happens if you tell them "no", and ask them to follow International standards instead of inventing their own?

Comment: It's the client, unfortunately. I've already asked them if they could do anything on their end to fix it, but apparently it's not an application that they have any control over, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I extended [XmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx) so that I could override the WriteEndElement() method, forcing it to call WriteFullEndElement(). This did the trick.

**Note:** for anybody that saw my question update, please ignore. IE was rendering the XML in the shorthand form. As soon as I opened it in Notepad, I realized everything was working fine.

```
public class FullEndingXmlTextWriter : XmlTextWriter
{
    public FullEndingXmlTextWriter(TextWriter w)
        : base(w)
    {
    }

    public FullEndingXmlTextWriter(Stream w, Encoding encoding)
        : base(w, encoding)
    {
    }

    public FullEndingXmlTextWriter(string fileName, Encoding encoding)
        : base(fileName, encoding)
    {
    }

    public override void WriteEndElement()
    {
        this.WriteFullEndElement();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it with a regular expression, making it a two-pass process.

```
string xml = "element foo=\"bar\" />"

string pattern = @"<(?<elem>\w+)(?<body>\b.*)/>";
string substitute =  @"<${elem} ${body}></${elem}>";

Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
string goodresult = regex.Replace(xml, substitute);
```

Answer (score 0):

Scott Hanselman wrote a while back an article about [stripping out empty elements](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/StrippingOutEmptyXmlElementsInAPerformantWayAndTheBusFactor.aspx) from XML, and at a glance the code can be used for your purpose with a small alteration to the treatment of empty elements. He also explains why using RegEx is a bad idea.

I am pointing this out, as I don't know of a way to get XmlSerializer to do what you want.

Another possibility, though I don't really know much about WPF is using the XAML serializer - look at the [System.Window.Markup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.aspx) namespace documentation.

Comment: Yes, it looks like Scott Hanselman has found a good and very optimized solution (to another problem), even though an XSLT transform would probably have been easier in that case if speed wasn't the main concern. I don't however share his opinions about RegEx, and apparently the have been using them for years. ;-)