# Creating specific XML with LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to create the following XML Element:

```
<result>
    <object1>VALUE_1</object1>
    <object2>VALUE_2</object2>
    <object3>VALUE_3</object3>
    <object4>VALUE_4</object4>
</result>
```

I have the following code:

```
XElement xResult = new XElement("node_results",
                from
                    a in entityResult
                select new XElement("result"
                    , new XElement("object1", a.VALUE_1
                    , new XElement("object2", a.VALUE_2)
                    , new XElement("object3", a.VALUE_3)
                    , new XElement("object4", a.VALUE_4)
                )
            );
```

This code generate this XML:

```
<node_results>
    <result>
        <object1>VALUE_1</object1>
        <object2>VALUE_2</object2>
        <object3>VALUE_3</object3>
        <object4>VALUE_4</object4>
    </result>
</node_results>
```

How can I generate the resulting xml without the tag "node_results"?

I already used these codes, but generate errors:

```
XElement xResult =
                from
                    a in entityResult
                select new XElement("result"
                    , new XElement("object1", a.VALUE_1
                    , new XElement("object2", a.VALUE_2)
                    , new XElement("object3", a.VALUE_3)
                    , new XElement("object4", a.VALUE_4)
            );

or

XElement xResult = new XElement("result",
                from
                    a in entityResult
                select
                     new XElement("object1", a.VALUE_1)
                    , new XElement("object2", a.VALUE_2)
                    , new XElement("object3", a.VALUE_3)
                    , new XElement("object4", a.VALUE_4)
                )
            );
```

Comment: What errors? Always include them in a question.

Answer (score 0):

The `entityResult` is apparently an array of results so you can't assign it to an XElement, but must create a IEnumerable of them.

This should work:

```
var xResults =
            from
                a in entityResult
            select new XElement("result"
                , new XElement("object1", a.VALUE_1
                , new XElement("object2", a.VALUE_2)
                , new XElement("object3", a.VALUE_3)
                , new XElement("object4", a.VALUE_4)
        );
```

The important difference is that the xResults will be a `IEnumerable<XElement>`, so the result is something like:

```
<result>
   <object1>VALUE_1</object1>
   <object2>VALUE_2</object2>
   <object3>VALUE_3</object3>
   <object4>VALUE_4</object4>
</result>
<result>
   <object1>VALUE_1</object1>
   <object2>VALUE_2</object2>
   <object3>VALUE_3</object3>
   <object4>VALUE_4</object4>
</result>
...
```

You will therefore need to wrap them in a root element. A second way would be to enumerate just one of the results:

```
XElement xResult = new XElement("result"
                , new XElement("object1", entityResult[0].VALUE_1
                , new XElement("object2", entityResult[0].VALUE_2)
                , new XElement("object3", entityResult[0].VALUE_3)
                , new XElement("object4", entityResult[0].VALUE_4) );
```

That really depends on what you need or want to do.

To prevent self closing tags, just replace null values with empty strings:

```
XElement xResult = new XElement("result"
                , new XElement("object1", entityResult[0].VALUE_1 ?? ""
                , new XElement("object2", entityResult[0].VALUE_2 ?? "")
                , new XElement("object3", entityResult[0].VALUE_3 ?? "")
                , new XElement("object4", entityResult[0].VALUE_4 ?? "") );
```

The **??** operator checks, if the left-hand side is equal to null and in case it not, outputs this left-side value, otherwise outputs the right-hand value.

EDIT2: Apparently this doesn't work - so another soluition - [How do you force explicit tag closing with Linq XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355147/how-do-you-force-explicit-tag-closing-with-linq-xml) . Take a look at the answer by R. Martinho Fernandes - he has a full example of creating a custom XMLWriter that solves your problem.

Comment: This code works. Thanks MZetko.
Is there a way to not show the tag <object> when the value of the element is null?
When is null, the xml show a tag <object/>.

Comment: Then you can use conditional if null in the code: example for the second line - ... entityResult[0].VALUE_2 ?? "" )

Comment: Updated my answer with a sample.

Comment: The ?? operador doesn´t work. If the value is null or empty, the xml generated contains self closing tags.
Is there another way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `entityResult` is a collection containing only a single element.

```
var a = entityResult.Single();
XElement xResult = XElement("result",
    new XElement("object1", a.VALUE_1),
    new XElement("object2", a.VALUE_2),
    new XElement("object3", a.VALUE_3),
    new XElement("object4", a.VALUE_4));
```