# How to output "FullEndElement()" for XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2015, linq-to-xml

I have an XDocument that I want to write to a file (listed below under "//XDocument" comment) but once I use my writing method, which is written below under "//writing method" comment, I got an incomplete ending like "`</>`" instead of full ending like "`</script>"`. I need to fix this somehow.

My code:

```
private static void Execute()
{
    string outputXMLFile = outputXMLFile = @"C:\Temp\testPoints6.html";

    //XDocument
    XDocument documentElement = 
        new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration(
                "1.0", 
                Encoding.Default.ToString(), null
            )
                , 
            new XDocumentType(
                "html", null, null, null
            ));

    XElement html = new XElement("html");
    XElement head = new XElement("head");

    html.Add(new XAttribute("lang", "ru"));
    head.Add(
        new XElement("title",
    "Exported X3DOM Scene"));
    head.Add(
        new XElement("meta",
        new XAttribute("http-equiv", "X-UA-Compatible"),
        new XAttribute("content", "chrome=1")));
    head.Add(
        new XElement("meta",
        new XAttribute("http-equiv", "Content-Type"),
        new XAttribute("content", "text/html;charset=utf-8")));
    head.Add(
        new XElement("link",
        new XAttribute("rel", "stylesheet"),
        new XAttribute("type", "text/css"),
        new XAttribute("href", "http://www.x3dom.org/x3dom/release/x3dom.css")));
    head.Add(
        new XElement("script",
        new XAttribute("type", "text/javascript"),
        new XAttribute("src", "http://www.x3dom.org/x3dom/release/x3dom.js")
    ));

    html.Add(head);

    documentElement.Add(html);

    //writing method
    XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
    xws.Encoding = Encoding.Default;
    xws.Indent = true;
    xws.NewLineOnAttributes = true;
    using ( XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(outputXMLFile, xws) ) {
        documentElement.WriteTo(xw);
        xw.Flush();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html
  lang="ru">
  <head>
    <title>Exported X3DOM Scene</title>
    <meta
      http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
      content="chrome=1" />
    <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Type"
      content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="http://www.x3dom.org/x3dom/release/x3dom.css" />
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="http://www.x3dom.org/x3dom/release/x3dom.js" />
  </head>
</html>
```

So I need this XmlWriter to write "`<script> </script>`" to my file instead of "`<script .../>`" which is incorrect and cause some troubles when I run it in my browser

I took "the solution" to include closing tag  from this post : "[How do you force explicit tag closing with Linq XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355147/how-do-you-force-explicit-tag-closing-with-linq-xml)" but it does not seem to be working

Comment: "I took "the solution" to include closing tag ..." - apparently, you *didn't*. At least not in the code you've posted. The idea of that solution is to add the element (`"script"` for example) and explicitly setting the value to `string.Empty` (or `""`). -- So try `var scriptElement = new XElement("script", string.Empty); head.Add(scriptElement);` and then add the attributes to `scriptElement`.

Comment: Corak, Oh, yeah, thanks xD It works. Before I realized it, I just took one of the code examples and did not try the  other code samples and other solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it.

I wrote 2 functions to add full endings for the whole document :

```
private static void AddStringEmptyAfterEveryElement(XDocument documentElement)
{
    AddStringEmptyAfterElement(documentElement.Root);
}

private static void AddStringEmptyAfterElement(XElement rootElement)
{
    foreach ( XElement element in rootElement.Descendants() ) {
        if ( element.HasElements ) {
            AddStringEmptyAfterElement(element);
        }
        element.Add(String.Empty);
    }
}
```