Self closing tags in powertools
in open OpenXmlPowerTools self closing tags are implemented for all elements when empty.
E.g.
<div />

or
 <td />

This is not valid html. How to prevent this.
Or have I to regex me through the result to replace them :-(
But it seems, this is not a problem of the powertools. linq to xml does this:
var tc = new XElement(W.tc);

results in
<tc xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" />

So is there a way to prevent this?

I found a little bit similar question in:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355147/how-do-you-force-explicit-tag-closing-with-linq-xml
but this would make it a lot of effort.

In case somebody else has this problem, here is what I will use:
With the help of ChatGpt (with lot of tries) a regex is now my solution:
You can call the function e.g. with
string fixedHtml = FixSelfClosingTags(htmlContent,"div|a|td");

just pipe seperated tags
public static string FixSelfClosingTags(string html, string tags)    {
        
        //({tags}): Captures the specified tags (e.g., div, a, td)
        //(\s[^>]*)?: Captures the space and attributes if they exist, ensuring that the space is only added if attributes are present. 
        // If there are no attributes, this group is optional, avoiding extra spaces.
        
        string pattern = $@"<({tags})(\s[^>]*)?\/>";
        
        //string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attributes): 
        // This condition checks if there are no attributes or just whitespace. If true, it converts the tag into <tag></tag> without any space.
        // Otherwise: The tag is converted with attributes, preserving the space.
        // 
        
        string fixedHtml = Regex.Replace(html, pattern, m =>
        {
            string tagName = m.Groups[1].Value;
            string attributes = m.Groups[2].Value;
           
            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attributes)
                ? $"<{tagName}></{tagName}>" 
                : $"<{tagName}{attributes}></{tagName}>"; 
        });

    return fixedHtml;
}

